# How can i use two methods in the same select v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select with two choices. Can i use one method for choice?

This is my select:

```html
<select :value="selected" @change="sortAZ">
   <option disabled value="">Ordina per</option>
   <option>A-Z</option>
   <option>Z-A</option>
</select>
```

But with this selection I can only use the `sortAZ` method for each choice.

So, I have two methods: `sortAZ` and `sortZA`, I would like to use a method for the first option and a method for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the currently selected value, and decide which method to call on onchange handler.

```
<select :v-model="selected" @change="sort" ">
   <option disabled value="">Ordina per</option>
   <option>A-Z </option>
   <option>Z-A</option>
</select>

methods:{
  sort(){
    if(selected == 'A-Z'){
      callSortAZ();
    }
    else if(selected == 'Z-A'){
      callSortZA();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-model` you can update the local variable `selected` value then read the value of `selected` from inside the method & do AtoZ or ZtoA sort.

```html
<template>
  <select v-model="selected" @change="handleSort" ">
    <option disabled value="">Ordina per</option>
    <option value="az">A-Z </option>
    <option value="za">Z-A</option>
  </select>

</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: ''
  },
  methods: {
    handleSort() {
      const selectedVal = this.selected;

      if (selectedVal === 'az') {
        // sort a to z, call other method
        ...
      } else if (selectedVal === 'za') {
         // sort z to a, call other method
         ... 
      } else {
         ...
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `v-model` directive to bind the selected option value. Then check which value is selected in the change method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {selected:''},
  methods: {
    sorter: function() {
        if (this.selected === 'A-Z') {
          // the logic for A-Z sorting... 
          console.log('A-Z option selected')
        } else if (this.selected === 'Z-A') {
          // the logic for Z-A sorting... 
          console.log('Z-A option selected')
        }   
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected" @change="sorter" >
     <option disabled value="">Ordina per</option>
     <option value='A-Z'>A-Z</option>
     <option value='Z-A'>Z-A</option>
  </select>
</div>
```